# How to show only domain name or custom url in the address bar?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Once logged in, the webpage should go to user page but url should show only custom url.

**For example:**

If I have a form in `www.example.com/startups/registration/fill_form` once I logged in, it displays as `www.example.com/startups/registration/username`.

**Expected output:**
Once logged in successfully, it should redirect to `www.example.com/startups/registration/username` page but url should be be displayed like `www.example.com/username`.

As facebook, though we logged in, it will display url as `www.facebook.com`

I had gone through routing technique. Routing does like from the existing url, we can redirect to expected page. Now I want a reverse technique, when redirecting to expected page, url should be displayed as custom url.

I need like URL masking or display custom url using frameset or iframe as such.

check this [website](http://www.yourdomain.com/). Whatever option we click, it will redirect to the desired page but url in the address bar remains the same. I want exactly like that.

Comment: username is static name or dynamic name ?

Answer (score 1):

If logged in, address bar should show only domain name

```
 $route['default_controller'] = '****'; // mantion the desired controller after login IN
```

And mantion the redirect(); function in end of login success functionality.

Then If you logged then automatically redirect to your domain name only. but call the your default controller in background process.

Comment: Important: need to be placed at the end of `routes.php` file because of wild card precedence.

Comment: No, because I didn't ask tho. :D Just made a note to avoid eventual further problems to asker. You can edit answer and mention that rule as well.

Comment: Actually I want like URL masking, routing and htaccess will only help to redirect to a related webpage based on the custom url..  But I want to display custom url on a address bar. I will not type custom  url to get the desired page. When logged in, address bar should show only domain name .

Comment: I have updated my post, can you check that and let me know whether this will help

Comment: are you need start page also domain.com and then login also display domain.com ?

Comment: When user logged in successfully, whatever they click in the website, it should show only as `www.domainname/$username`. Now I have my application in `www.domainname/project` folder so , it displays as `www.domainname/project/startup/registration/profile` . Here startup and registration is controller and method.. Now I want it to be displayed as, `www.domainname/$uername` alone through out the session till they sign out

Comment: I say the another answer in this post ? you given url is display based on iframe.

Comment: create one project in codeigniter and then pin that project other domain project iframe, that it

Comment: In that same domain itself, I should do.Like this  `<frame src="http://domain.com/rony/startups/login" title="domain.com" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"/>`  in index.php . If I type `http://domain.com/` through out the page it should display like this only

Comment: I did it worked. Throughout the session, url remains the same. But if user logged in successfully how can I change status bar from `domain.com` to `domain.com/$username`?

Comment: Yes. But different domain needed.

Comment: Glad to help, can  you accept my answer and comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Well... you need to use .htaccess to handle this issue. Just take a look following tutorial for your better understanding...

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049
- http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/
- http://www.9lessons.info/2013/11/htaccess-file-tutorial-and-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

You say http://www.yourdomain.com/ site

That site screens from https://www.1and1.com/?kwk=77902898  using iframes.

So only If you click login button, then only redirect inside of iframe.

Without change URL.

If you need same format, then apply one domain in another domain using iframe

Comment: Glad to help, can you accept that answer and upvote ?